# html5 doctype attributes

Tags: html, doctype

I have updated my sites doctype from XHTML to HTML5,

I currently have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-GB" xml:lang="en-GB" dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

my question is, are the attributes xml:lang and xmlns still required as I have migrated from xml to html, i'm thinking not but would like to know if there area any situations in which they should be maintained?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [global attributes](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/global-attributes.html).

You should only use the xml attributes if you have aa xml document ([http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#the-lang-and-xml:lang-attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#the-lang-and-xml%3alang-attributes))